# Micrometer tracing context propagration is lost in webclient flatMap function

Tags: spring-boot, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing, otel

Project: https://github.com/Jojoooo1/spring-microservice-webhook-reactive

Version:

- spring boot: 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT
- micrometer-tracing 1.12.0-M2

Even after using `Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation()` it seems that nested context does not propagate. **It was previously working using sleuth.**

**First context:**

[image]

**Second context**
[image]

Does anyone had similar issue and was able to fix it ?

Comment: I upgraded to    'io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.6.0' and i got it to work.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/2560 solved my problem.

Comment: @Trind Could you turn your remark into an answer? Because it solved my problem. Wasted over a day hunting what turned out to be a bug in Reactor.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/2560 has solved the problem.

The context is being lost between webclient and rabbit listener you need to add `.tap(Micrometer.observation(this.registry))`:

```
return this.webClient
        .post()
        .uri(url)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .headers(
            httpHeaders ->
                headers.forEach((k, v) -> httpHeaders.add(k, v != null ? v.toString() : null)))
        .bodyValue(requestBody)
        .exchangeToMono(this::defaultResponseHandler)
        .tap(Micrometer.observation(this.registry))
```

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded to 'io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.6.0' and I got it to work.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Automatic Context Propagation](https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/30/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-3-unified-bridging-between-reactive) since version 3.5.3 of reactor-core following line should be added in one place inside the application :

```
    Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
```